# Trying to send mail with c# Error: too many errors

Tags: c#, smtp

I am trying to send mail to approx. 2000 users. I am sure there is nothing wrong with credentails.

This is my code:

```
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
client.EnableSsl = false;
client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
client.Host = "---";
client.Port = 587;
client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("---", "---");

MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
msg.Body = "dfsdf";
msg.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
msg.Subject = "sdfsdf";
msg.From = new MailAddress("---");

msg.Bcc.Clear();
MembershipUserCollection muc = Membership.GetAllUsers();
foreach (MembershipUser mu in muc)
{
    msg.Bcc.Add(mu.Email);
}

try
{
    client.Send(msg);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Label_info.Text = ex.Message;
    if (ex.InnerException != null) Label_info.Text += "<br />" + ex.InnerException.Message;
    return;
}
```

This is the exception i get:
 Service not available, closing transmission channel. The server response was: 4.7.0 [my smtp name] Error: too many errors

Comment: Try sending one email to a hardcoded email address.  Narrow down the scope of this problem to either a coding problem, email format problem or network security problem.

Comment: Try catching the more specific `SMTPException`, then look at the value of `StatusCode` - compare against the [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpstatuscode.aspx) on this and it might give everyone some more information.

Comment: Does each email address exist in the mail server?  Does this smtp mail server allow for "spamming"?  Many questions here and P.Brian.Mackey nailed it on the head.

Comment: brian, i did what u said. no problem occured. mail sent

Comment: bridge, i did what u said. exception is still same. status code is ServiceNotAvailable. it corresponds to: The SMTP service is not available; the server is closing the transmission channel.

Comment: steve i know that about %5 of this emails dont exist or their mailbox is unavailable. but most of them are valid. am i trying to spam now? :(

Comment: Are you trying to send 1 message out to 2000 addresses? That is your problem. You can only send an email out to so many addressees at once. Try breaking down your email list to sending out 1 new message per 20 (or part there of), and it will probably send out these spam messages of yours.

Comment: Let put your SmtpClient client in the using statement to make sure dispose was done.
`using (SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient())
{
     client.Send(msg);
}`